Understanding the 4-dimensional integral of stochastic quantum mechanics
I'm studying stochastic quantization from this paper. I want to understand the 4 dimensional integral \eqref{eq:235} and to be able to compute \eqref{eq:237a} and \eqref{eq:237b} in the end,

\begin{equation}\label{eq:235}
D(x-x',t-t')=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4} \int \mathrm{d}^4k\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}e^{ik(x-x')-(k^2+m^2)|t-t'|}\tag{2.35}
\end{equation}
which immediately yields
\begin{equation}\label{eq:236}
D(x-x',0)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int\mathrm{d}^4k\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}e^{ik(x-x')}=\Delta(x-x').
\tag{2.36}
\end{equation}
Thus we have obtained exactly the same free propagator as given by the conventional method, via the route of SQM. The asymptotic behaviors of $D(x,t)$ in $x$ and in $t$ are, respectively
\begin{equation}\label{eq:237a}
D(x,0)\ _\overrightarrow{_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}} \frac{m^2}{16\pi^3}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m|x|}\right)^{3/2}\exp\left[-m|x|\right]\tag{2.37a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:237b}
D(0,t)\ _\overrightarrow{_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}} \frac{m^2}{16\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{m^2|t|}\right)^2\exp\left[-m^2|t|\right].\tag{2.37b}
\end{equation}

The integral is evaluated in the phase space, where the original coordinate is a four dimensional euclidean space. I tried to evaluate the integral in four-dimensional spherical coordinate $$\mathrm{d}^4 k = k^3 \sin^2\omega \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}k \, \mathrm{d}\omega \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi.\label{eq1} \tag{1} $$
Using this method to evaluate $D(0,t)$ first, I got
$$ \frac{1}{16 \pi^2 |t|} e^{-m^2 |t|} \label{eq2} \tag{2} $$
in the limit $t \rightarrow \infty$, which is different from \eqref{eq:237b}. What is the correct approach to solve this integral? I thought starting with \eqref{eq1} and doing the integral explicitly would be enough, but I still don't understand, could there me more into higher dimensional integral that I don't understand here? Or perhaps some assumptions in the topics of stochastic quantization?
Any help would be meaningful. If this question is not appropriate, please help me to improve my way of asking in the community. Thanks!
Edit
Thank you for Prahar for helping to find \eqref{eq:237b}. I will write the solution I just obtained for \eqref{eq:237a}
The integral \eqref{eq:236} can be written according to the integration parameters \eqref{eq1} with $k \in [0,\infty)$, $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, $\omega \in [0,\pi]$, and $\phi \in [0,2 \pi)$
\begin{align}
D(x,0)
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int \mathrm{d}k \, \mathrm{d}\omega \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi
\frac{k^3 \sin^2\omega \sin\theta}{k^2+m^2}e^{ik\cdot x}
\end{align}
From this step, I use Mathematica.
Now, I it seems that I can choose whether to write $k\cdot x = k \, x \cos\theta$ or $k\cdot x = k \, x \cos\omega$. The former will give me a result which involves Meijer-G Function, which is quite inconvenient. Choosing $k\cdot x = k \, x \cos\omega$ will give me a result which involves Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind,
\begin{align}
D(x,0)&= \frac{1}{16\pi^2} \frac{4\pi^2 m}{|x|} \, K_1(m|x|)
\end{align}
In the large $x$ limit,
\begin{align}
K_1(m|x|) &= e^{-m|x|} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \frac{1}{(m|x|)^{1/2}}+\frac{3}{8 (|m|x)^{3/2}} + \cdots \right)
\end{align}
Keeping the dominant term, I obtained the desired result,
\begin{align}
D(x,0)\ _\overrightarrow {_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}} &
\frac{1}{16\pi^2} \frac{4\pi^2 m}{|x|}e^{-m|x|} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2mx}}\\
&= \frac{m^2}{16\pi^3} \frac{2\pi }{m|x|}e^{-m|x|} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{mx}}\\
&= \frac{m^2}{16\pi^3} \left(\frac{2\pi }{m|x|}\right)^{3/2}e^{-m|x|}
\end{align}
Closing Statement
Thank you for all the feedbacks and edits!

Well you haven't even shown what you did besides showing the result and the integration measure....so we have no idea how you computed the integral.

Welcome Alfian. One thing you can do better in future posts is to use MathJax for equations and the ">" markup character in particular, for equations and/or text that you want to cite. In general, we discourage attaching text and equations as images.

Mathematica tells me the integral is
$$
D(0,t) = \frac{1}{16\pi^2|t| } \left[ e^{-m^2|t|} - m^2|t| \, \Gamma(0,m^2 |t|) \right]
$$
At large $|t|$, we have
$$
D(0,t) \to e^{-m^2|t|} \left[ \frac{1}{16\pi^2 m^2 t^2} - \frac{1}{8\pi^2 m^4 |t|^3} + O(|t|^{-4}) \right] 
$$
